# What is tilde in this context of R?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

```
  mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_map(~ head(.x, 2L))
```

Can anyone explain last line of code part?
I know about the pipe but what is `~ head(.x, 2L)`?

Comment: For every group, print head. It's tidy syntax. Compare it to `purrr::map(~head(.x))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a shorthand for an anonymous function that is applied to every group. `.x` is automatically the input in `purrr` style anonymous functions (and additionally `.y` for `map2` functions).

But you can use a traditional anonymous functions as well:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_map(., function(x) head(x, 2L)) # the `.` is just for illustration and can be omitted with the %>%
```

Or you can write a named function and use it in `group_map()`:

```
new_fun <- function(x) {
   head(x, 2L)
}
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_map(new_fun)
```

The function you show (`head(.x, 2L)`) is applied once to every group in the data. You can check how many groups you have with:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  n_groups()
#> [1] 3
```

For each of these groups, the first two rows of the data is printed:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_map(~ head(.x, 2L)) 
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 10
#>     mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  22.8  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#> 2  24.4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 10
#>     mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    21   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#> 2    21   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 10
#>     mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  18.7   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#> 2  14.3   360   245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
```

Comment: Suggestion to add a line that shows `n_groups` to explain why there are only 3 list values.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I just thought it would be easier to show how `group_map` works if we showed `n_groups`(3) and that this is why the result is of length 3.

Comment: No, `~` is meant to work inside `map` functions from the `purrr` package.  It has nothing to do with the `%>%`.

Comment: I got the code you explain but what is the meaing of  ~ and .x ?

Comment: `~` is short for `function(.x)` above I used `function(x)` as this is the traditional way of writing it. From there it is really just a simple anonymous (i.e., unnamend) function.